# Have Tomcat JDBCRealm use a different column for returned username

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat8, servlet-3.0, jdbcrealm

Is it possible to have Tomcat with JDBC Realm Form Authentication return a different user table column as "username" instead of the username supplied at login?

Use case:
In my application I use *servletRequest.getUserPrincipal()* and cast it to *org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal*. Now I want to use the **ID** instead of the **loginname** of the current user for tasks like filling out a "created_by" column in a database table.
This column is a number column and not a string, for various reasons (data volume, possibility to change the loginname, ...)

I did not see an attribute for this in the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) or the [JDBCRealm-docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/realm.html#JDBC_Database_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm).

I'd need a new attribute ***userIdCol*** and have it available in *GenericPrincipal* as well.
Even better would be if the ID was available in the HttpServletRequest directly if the new attribute is used.

I'm pretty sure that this is not possible out of the box, but wanted to ask anyway, as the request itself (have and id-number instead of an id-string) does seem very common to me.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Tomcat's existing code.

Here's how I handle it: when a user logs in, I load a `User` object and put it into the `HttpSession`. The `User` object contains the user's numeric identifier. Whenever I need to perform some database operation, I pass the current `User` from the `HttpSession` into the method that performs that operation. Now, the code that handles the database calls has access to the user's numeric identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing the same but was wondering if there is a better solution to this use case, as in my opinion almost every application will need to do something like this.